# Are ties possible?

Tags: magikarp-jump

What happens if, by some chance, both your and the opponent's Magikarp have exactly the same JP, right down to the last digit?

Does the game recognise a tie? Or does it rule in favour of one or the other fish?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As it happens...

A Lv80 Magikarp caps out at 1,986,589,014 JP. [source](http://www.serebii.net/magikarpjump/raisingmagikarp.shtml)
The 5th Magikarp in the Expert 1 League has... 1,986,589,014 JP. [source](http://www.serebii.net/magikarpjump/leagues/expertleague1.shtml)

My Magikarp did not receive a cheer from the support Pokémon, so it should have been a tie. Despite this, the result was:

Springboard: 174.85m
Koylee: 174.84m

In the event of a tie, the player wins. Additionally, the "JP => jump height" formula seems to include a bit where if the result would be identical to the opponent, it increments the winner by one in the least significant digit.

I then got two 25% and a 5% cheer in a row so I wasn't able to get any more data out of Springboard. On to the next Magikarp:

Thanks to the ability to skip previously won battles, I was able to avoid the chance of cheers and this is what the 4th-6th battles gave:

Bouncycastle: 174.84m
Magikarp: 171.37m

Bouncycastle: 174.85m
Koylee: 174.84m

Bouncycastle: 174.84m
Magikarp: 175.53m

This conclusively proves that the game will inflate the score of the winning Magikarp if they would otherwise appear equal, and that ties are resolved in the player's favour.

Answer (score -1):

According to [this Reddit PSA](https://www.reddit.com/r/MagikarpJump/comments/6egx4t/psa_if_you_tie_the_opponents_jump_you_will_still/), if there is a tie, you are the winner.

However, the sourcing in this PSA is admittedly dubious without a screenshot, especially since, as you alluded to, it would be extremely difficult to know if yours and your opponent's Magikarp have precisely the same JP (due to the game's rounding).

As such, it is safer to use a Magikarp that has a higher JP (even by .1) to ensure you will win.